# Android: using jackson to parse JSON object by object

Tags: android, json, jackson, arrays

I want to access data from a database in my android app. For this, I'm using a PHP webservice and JSON format data. When I ask the webservice for data, I get something like this:

```
{"products":
  [
    {"product":["prod_id_1","prod_name_1","prod_barcode_1","prod_brand_1","prod_wrapper_1","12.00000"]},
    {"product":["prod_id_2","prod_name_2","prod_barcode_2","prod_brand_2","prod_wrapper_2","24.00000"]}
  ]
}
```

But with 1000+ products. Obviously, jsonObject and jsonArray are inneficient for this. So I'd like to use Jackson streaming json parser. I can't keep a list of products in my app, as that would consume much memory. So what I want to do is to read one product from the json, write it at my android SQLite database, read the next product, write it to database and so on.

I've seen this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) but if I used this, I'd have to use a list of products. So my question is, how can I read this jsonarray, product by product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Should anyone need this, here's how I solved it, as learned from  [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

```
JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser( httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler) );

jp.nextToken();

while(jp.nextToken()!=JsonToken.END_OBJECT){
    jp.nextToken();
    while (jp.nextToken()!=JsonToken.END_ARRAY){
        jp.nextToken();
        while(jp.nextToken()!=JsonToken.END_OBJECT){
                String fieldname = jp.getCurrentName();

                while (jp.nextToken()!=JsonToken.END_ARRAY){                            
                       produto p_json = new produto(); //produto is my product class
                        p_json.id = Integer.parseInt(jp.getText());
                    jp.nextToken();
                    p_json.name = jp.getText();
                    jp.nextToken();

                    p_json.cod_barras = jp.getText(); //product barcode
                    jp.nextToken();
                    p_json.marca = jp.getText(); //product brand
                    jp.nextToken();

                    String formato = jp.getText(); //product wrapper
                    jp.nextToken();
                    p_json.formato = formato+"["+jp.getText()+"]"; //formatting as required by my database, as wrapper+"["+number+"]"

                    //The following line writes the product in the database...
                    bd.addProduto(p_json);
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    jp.close(); // ensure resources get cleaned up timely and
                            // properly
```